# OpenGL vertex arrays, drawing from user input

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, glut

I am trying to take user input in the form of left and right clicks to draw a polygon to the screen.  Every left click is captured as an (x,y) coordinate and saved into an array.  After the user pressed the right click, the mouse function should finish the polygon (connect the last point to the original) and display it to the screen.  I have verified using my code in the display function with hardcoded values using the vertex array, so I think the issue is to do with how I handle the termination condition (i.e. "GLUT_RIGHT_CLICK")
Can you see an error here?  When I test the function it crashes on right click.

```
void mouseMove(int click, int state, int x, int y)
{
    clearFramebuffer();
    static int i = 0;
    drawit();
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    while(click!=GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON){
        if(click==GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN){

            vertices[i]=x;
            vertices[i+1]=y;
            //{10, 10, 10, 50, 50, 50, 50, 10};
            //printf("Coords:  (%d,%d)\n",vertices[i],vertices[i+1]);
            i++;i++;
        }
    }
    //drawit();
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_INT, 0, vertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_POLYGON, 0, 10);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);  
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

mouseMove is called in the main like so:

```
glutMouseFunc( mouseMove );
```

This is part of my homework so any other solution not involving vertex arrays is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

This function is called each time the mouse is pressed so no need for a loop in there. Here is one suggestion as how you can solve your issue. It is not the best one but will work. Please note that you can draw only convex polygons this way, otherwise you need for instance tesselation:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int> > points;
void UnprojectPoint(std::pair<int,int> point, 
    std::pair<double,double>& unprojected) {
  double modelview[16], projection[16];
  int viewport[4];
  double objz;

  //get the modelview matrix        
  glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
  //get the projection matrix
  glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
  //get the viewport        
  glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );

  //Unproject the window co-ordinates to 
  //find the world co-ordinates.
  gluUnProject( x, y, 0, modelview, projection, viewport, 
      &unprojected.first, &&unprojected.second, &objz);
}

void MousePressFunc(int button, int state, int x, int y) { 
  if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
    points.push_back(std::make_pair(x, y));
  } else if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP) {
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      for (unsigned index = 0; index < points.size(); ++index) {
        std::pair<double, double> unprojected;
        UnprojectPoint(points[index], unporjected);
        glVertex2f(unprojected.first, unprojected.second);
      }
    glEnd(); // GL_POLYGON
    points.clear(); // Clear the polygon.
  }
}
```

Please note that you need to unproject the point to convert it from window coordinates to world coordinates.
Hope this helps.